# Search codes in a Text in PHP

Tags: php, regex, search, full-text-search

I want to find "codes" in a text, these codes can contain letters and numbers and could have a different length. A text could look like this:

```
This is a example text, it contains different codes like this one 8de96217e0fd4c61a8aa7e70b3eb68 or that one a7ac356448437db693b5ed6125348.
```

How can I find and echo them in the correct order (from the first to the last one).
I think there is a way with prey_match(), but I don't know how to make regular expressions. Additional information: the codes are all about 30 characters long and contain only lower letters and numbers.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: preg_match operates on patterns. if you don't have a pattern, then you might need prey_match() indeed. do you know what the codes might be like i.e. are more than 25 characters etc?

Comment: [Here's a regex tutorial](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm).

Comment: Can you define what the codes are more definitively? One way to do this would be to `explode` the string into words using space, and then omit words that are just made up of characters or punctuation.

Comment: Those look like md5 hashes, are they all 32 long?

Comment: @WouterH they look like md5 hashes but they're not exactly 32 chars long

Comment: You could try a pattern similar to this `\b([a-f0-9]{16,})\b`. _It could generate false positives but matches md4, md5 ans sha1._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/[a-z0-9]{25,}/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Simple but should work for your case.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8de96217e0fd4c61a8aa7e70b3eb68
            [1] => a7ac356448437db693b5ed6125348
        )

)
```

Comment: this is the best answer, shouldnt be on bottom of the page. upping.

Comment: Wouldn't that match any word made up of letters or numbers?

Comment: I think this is the right way, but it matches with every word not only with number-and-letter words.

Comment: Corrected, tested and changed my answer.. ;-)

Comment: there was {30}, he just edited because of dynamic length, i think.

Comment: [pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism)

Comment: Nice i tried it again and it works perfectly, thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Pascal Gläser You are welcome.

Comment: @alpera I had {30,} was on my post. If I recall, this one didn't have a length on it at all originally.

Comment: If that comment sounded too.. ragey, I didn't intend for that. Sorry!

Comment: @BrandonJ.Dusseau, sorry.. lost in too many questions,answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$string = "This is a example text, it contains different codes like this one 8de96217e0fd4c61a8aa7e70b3eb68 or that one a7ac356448437db693b5ed6125348."
preg_match_all("/[0-9a-z]{30,}/", $string, $matches)
```

Where `$matches` is an array containing all matches. You can adjust the {30,} to a higher or lower number if you'd like. That's just the number of consecutive characters.

Answer (score 0):

basicly,

```
$words = explode($text);
foreach($words as $word)
{
  if(strlen($word)==30)
    echo $word;
}
```

if you want to eliminate letters like #+$*... you should use regex

edit: Forlan07's answer is obviously better.

Comment: From OP: *codes can contain letters and numbers and **could have a different length**.*

Comment: What about the word `pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism`? :p

Comment: pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism :)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is that the "hashes" have *both* letters and numbers you could try something similar to this:

```
$string = "This is a example text, it contains different codes like this one 8de96217e0fd4c61a8aa7e70b3eb68 or that one a7ac356448437db693b5ed6125348.";

$words = explode(" ", $string);
$hashes = array();

foreach ($words as $currWord)
{
    $hasLetter = false;
    $hasNumber = false;

    for ($index = 0; $index < strlen($currWord); $index++)
    {
        if (ctype_alpha($string[$index]))
            $hasLetter = true;
        else
            $hasNumber = true;
    }

    if ($hasLetter && $hasNumber)
        $hashes[] = $currWord;
}
```